# PHP/MYSQL/APACHE: can't insert data to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, apache

Need your help. Currently my development server using Wamp server. please read below for services details:

- Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) PHP/5.3.0
- MySQL client version: mysqlnd 5.0.5-dev - 081106 - $Revision: 1.3.2.27 $
- PHP extension: mysqli
- Server: localhost (MySQL host info: localhost via TCP/IP)
- Server version: 5.1.36-community-log
- Protocol version: 10
- User: root@localhost
- MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

My production server using manual configuration. read below for details:

- Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) PHP/5.3.4
- MySQL client version: mysqlnd 5.0.7-dev - 091210 - $Revision: 304625 $
- PHP extension: mysql
- Server: localhost via TCP/IP
- Server version: 5.5.8
- Protocol version: 10
- User: root@localhost
- MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Im using PHP as web programming language. my problem is right now (production server), i cant insert data to table that have more then 40 fields.
but no problem with table that have 10, 7, 22, etc fields.
development server also got no problem with that 40fields.

what should I do now? please guide me.. thank you.

Comment: Try to post the error and code you tried

Comment: Why does your development (or at least your testing) environment not reflect your production environment?

Comment: the error was defined by me: if($result){success} else{error cant insert}....

Comment: dear ignacio, we're using different PC for development (using wamp server) and production (using manual configuration).

Comment: So, you have not to define error yourself but ask a database for this. mysql_error() and such

Comment: mysql_error() = Query was empty. please also refer this link for further information, http://www.daniweb.com/forums/post1426518.html#post1426518

Answer (score -1):

According to your environment your using 2 different PHP extension's (mysql and mysqli).

Comment: please sir guide me to change PHP extension from mysql to mysqli. I really don't have any idea how to setup this server. My programmer using wamp server to test his system, and my server admin setup a production server using manual configuration.. and my task right now to analyst what is the problem and fix it... thanks in advance.